# How to use multiple filepaths with spaces in find and grep

Tags: bash, shell

In Bash,
From a file I am reading the list of files matching a pattern to search in.
variable content will be something like this after reading

```
files="C:/Downloads/tutorial java*.txt D:/text materials*.java"
```

It is then used in find

```
find  $files -type f -exec grep -PrnIi my-search-term --color=auto {} /dev/null \;
```

I tried escaping space with '\' like this

```
files="C:/Downloads/tutorial\ java*.txt D:/text\ materials*.java".
```

But not working. I cannot hard code the list of files as it needs to be read from a different file

Comment: `C:/Downloads/tutorial java*.txt` looks more of a wild-card for a bunch of files than an actual path.

Comment: files can be like tutorial java1.txt and so on

Comment: You need to specify a path as an argument and not a list of files after `find ..`

Comment: Valid file paths are something like `C:/Downloads/` or `D:/text materials`

Comment: You properly don't even need to use `find` here.

Comment: I have to use find as i need to specify recurse and maxdepth for some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining paths with the patterns to match in those paths. That's fine, but you would need would need to search basically the entire file system for files matching the full paths.

```
 find / \( -path "C:/Downloads/tutorial java*.txt" -o -path "D:/text materials*.java" \) ...
```

If you want to store these in a variable, use an array, not a regular variable.

```
files=( "C:/Downloads/tutorial java*.txt" "D:/text materials*.java")
patterns=(-path "${files[0]}")
for pattern in "${files[@]:1}"; do
  patterns+=(-o -path "$pattern")
done
find / \( "${patterns[@]"} \)
```